# Django Foreign key on self

Tags: django, django-models

Model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, related_name='subcategories')
```

Database is hitted on every function call:

```
    def get_children(elem, lst):
        lst.append(elem.pk)
        children = elem.subcategories.all()
        if not children: return
        for c in children:
            get_children(c, lst)

lst=[]
get_children(Category.objects.prefetch_related('subcategories').get(pk=1), lst) # prefetch related is not working
```

How to fetch all table in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't fetch all children with one query.  You should consider to use [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) app for hierarchical data.

Comment: can I just load all query set in memory, like select * from table? It is not that big. approximately 200 rows.

Comment: Sure you can load all potential children and build desired list in the memory: `Category.objects.exclude(parent=None)`.

Comment: Can I load aboslutely all table, so that element.parent doesn't use database?

Comment: You can get parent id without any db hits: `category.parent_id`.